# Django: Models not being acknowledged locally

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting errors from django like this:

```
NameError at /
global name 'Article' is not defined
```

Now this only occurs locally, even though in the folder containing manage.py I ran `python manage.py syncdb`, it seems to make no difference when I run my project locally.

If its any help, I am running on openshift as my host and am using [this django](https://github.com/openshift/django-example) folder structure.

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you importing your model?
`from myapp.models import Article`

Comment: To a degree, he answered my question. But yea, if that wasn't the answer to the question - it would have been annoying. Regardless, thank you.